# Windows 7 monitor swapping bug

Tags: winapi, windows-7, multiple-monitors

I wrote a small application to switch the primary monitor on button click as follows:

```
Monitor 0 --> Monitor 1 --> Monitor 2
```

For every button click, the primary monitor switches between the three.

I am able to successfully switch the monitor every time I click the button and the monitor coordinates are supposed to be

```
(0,0)
(1920,0)
(3840,0)
```

I am also able to achieve it under all the three cases. However, when I try to switch the monitor from Monitor 2 to Monitor 0, the monitor coordinates returned are:

```
(0,0)
(0,0)
(1920,0)
```

The ChangeDisplaySettingEx function does not return any error and monitors just work as they are expected. Since the coordinates returned are incorrect, the windows that I am trying to position are placed incorrectly. The window that has to be placed on the second screen gets placed on the first.

Here is a code sample of how I am currently switching monitors:

```
             next_position++;

        if(next_position>2)
        {
            next_position=0;            
        }

     POINTL posPrimary={0};
     posPrimary.x=0
     posPrimary.y=0;

     DEVMODE mode_primary = {0};
     mode_primary.dmSize = sizeof(mode_primary);
     mode_primary.dmFields = DM_POSITION;
     mode_primary.dmPosition = posPrimary;

    LONG status = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
        nameofMonitor[next_position],
        &mode_primary,
        nullptr, // reserved
       CDS_SET_PRIMARY | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY,
        nullptr // no video parameter
    );
      if (DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL != status) {
        printf("ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returned %d", status);
        return -__LINE__;
    }

    int m =1;
    for(int var =0; var<=2;var++)
    {

         posPrimary.y=0;
         posPrimary.x=dxWidthPrimary*m;
         m++;
         DEVMODE mode_primary = {0};
         mode_primary.dmSize = sizeof(mode_primary);
         mode_primary.dmFields = DM_POSITION;
         mode_primary.dmPosition = posPrimary;

        if(var!=next_position)
        {
        status = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
        nameofMonitor[var],
        &mode_primary,
        nullptr, // reserved
       CDS_GLOBAL | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY,
        nullptr // no video parameter
    );
          if (DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL != status) {
        printf("ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returned %d", status);
        return -__LINE__;
    }
        }
    }


    ChangeDisplaySettingsEx (NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Since my code works as expected, should I just override this faulty condition by changing (0,0) to (3840,0)? I am not able to find the problem here